# Comparing the PCA modes from two different covariances

Tags: multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, pca, linear-model

Suppose I have a set of $n$ vectors $x_i$ arranged as columns of a matrix $X$ and I want to perform PCA to reduce the number of dimensions needed to explain some set of observations. I have developed two different ad hoc covariance matrices for my variables $x_i$: $C$ and $D$. I want to know how similar or different are the PC modes derived from each covariance.

So I compute the SVD in both cases:
$$
X L_C = U_C S_C V_C^T
$$
and
$$
X L_D = U_D S_D V_D^T
$$
where $L_C,L_D$ are the Cholesky factors of the covariance matrices $C,D$. I am interested to know:

1. Are the modes $U_C$ or $U_D$ more efficient at explaining my data?
2. How similar/different are the modes $U_C$ and $U_D$?

For question 2, does anyone know of some formalism for exploring the differences between two sets of modes? One possible approach would be to test to what degree do these two sets of modes span the same space? Another approach might be to project the modes $U_D$ onto the modes $U_C$ and define some kind of norm of the part that is lost in the projection.

Perhaps there already exists some nice formal way to look at this?

Comment: the concept of "angles between flats" may be of interest for problem 2 (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angles_between_flats).